# What is the correct term to describe a party to an action who is really only a sock puppet for the party's legal counsel and expert witness?

Tags: legal-terms

I have encountered a situation where one of the parties (a government department) is actually forced into their position by a combination of their legal counsel (DOJ) and expert witness (law enforcement), neither of whom they have any choice over, and with whom they do not necessarily agree.

Is there a name or legal term that describes a party in such a situation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your term.  A party to a lawsuit generally means a plaintiff or defendant.  Not sure how your lawyer can force you to bring or defend a lawsuit.

Comment: What do you mean by "forced into their position"? What "position"?

Comment: Government agencies sometimes find themselves compelled to take legal positions with which they do not agree but must accept the advice of government counsel.  In the cases of which I am aware the agency is commonly defending against an appeal of some administrative decision informed by representation of counsel and testimony of an expert witness from law enforcement, neither of which the agency has any control over employing.  This is not a theoretical situation but I am constrained from providing specifics.

Answer (score 2):

### Neither a lawyer nor an expert can *force* their client to do anything

Your doctor can tell you to eat less and exercise more - whether you do so is up to you.

The lawyer can advise their client. The expert can state their opinion. The client decides what to do about it.

Since the concept doesn’t really exist, it doesn’t need a name.

Answer (score 2):

Government agencies aren't legal people in most cases and thus can't be clients. In the case of the U.S. Federal Government, **the client is the United States government**.

The Department of Justice is the lawyer for the United States government and ultimately reports to the President of the United States. A U.S. government agency is not the client, it is just a subdivision of the United States government.